My starter tries to engage but hear it spinning
The starter in my 2013 dodge Durango crew tries to engage but just spins.
What could it be?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

If your starter whines like a jet engine, the starter one way bearing is damaged. The internal bearing clutch cannot be repaired. Replace the starter.

Either the clutch that allows the starter gear to engage is bad or a bad solenoid.
Either way, you'd have to replace the starter.

Depending on where Randy lives, it may be economically better to get the starter repaired at much better price than getting a new one.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
